# Difference between 0-18V and -9V - +9V

Tags: power-supply, voltage, negative-voltage

What is the principle of the difference between a supply which provides 0-18V and +9V and -9V?

If I am using a circuit which takes a +/-9V power supply, and instead start powering it with 2 9v batteries, is there a fundamental difference in the supply, or is it just a verbal one?

Comment: The -9 - +9V one probably has a 0V tap? In other words, 3 output wires instead of 2.

Comment: The difference is where you label as 0 V, or commonly ground.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

In this case  BAT1 has at the plus side 18 V, and at the BAT2 minus side 0 V, because GND is connected there.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fa9uP0.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Below, the GND is in between the batteries, so on either side the difference is 9V, resulting in +9V at the + side of BAT1 and -9V at the - side of BAT2.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fpeTk1.png)</sup>

Comment: +1 for the images.  I dunno if there's any way to shrink them a bit and put them side-by-side; having them next to each other might make it easier to see the difference.

Comment: @Nat Next to each other is not possible, but with adding some text the size is made smaller automatically.

Comment: Thanks for this. I have seen some circuits, particularly from older schematics, that use positive ground, so if using a 9V battery, you just swap the + and - leads around, but if using it on mains power it recommends a MAX1044 or 7660s to produce -9V. What is the difference between this and swapping the tip and sleeve connections of a power supply?

Comment: @TCassa I'm quite new to electronics. However, if GND is at the plus side, than the negative side would be the relative difference, which is -9 V indeed. I don't know what MAX1044 or 7660 do.

Answer (score 20):

Inherent in your description of +9 V and -9 V is a presumed 0 V connection. So you have two supplies: +9 V and -9 V

If you don't have this 0 V connection in any form, then your +9 V and -9 V can be renamed 0 V and 18 V. Technically, you could name them -2 V and +16 V, or -100 V and -82 V if you want. But this would be unconventional and very bad practice because it would mislead others into expecting a 0 V connection that they are referenced to. Keep it simple and conventional, your work has to be understood by others.

Comment: I encountered some circuits that would not work if the -xV wasn't absolutely negative.

Comment: @joshua, but negative relative to what? It's all relative, isn't it. You must have had a 0 V, ground, chassis ground, input ground, input 0 V or something then.

Comment: Relative to local vacuum (or more likely local air).

Comment: @joshua, you'll have to post far more detail for people to understand if there's a point you're making, not just one line I'm afraid

Comment: @Joshua how do you measure the voltage of the air or vacuum?

Comment: @immibis: That's actually a very good question. I don't know a single way to get the difference between a voltage source and air, but I know how to tell if that voltage source is above or below it. Take a block of iron. Put it on a block of wood or some other insulator. Put a mesh cage around it (to prevent interference). After some time its charge potential will equalize with the surrounding air (if your cage is good enough we also know this will be zero). Measure your potential with the iron block.

Comment: There's a constant of proportionality I can't remove in this setup so it only yields the sign of the voltage.

Comment: @Joshua That's not how electricity works.

Answer (score 13):

A supply that provides 0 volts and +18 volts can be assumed to have only two connections. A supply that provides +9 volts and -9 volts can be assumed to have a centre (0 volts) connection making it much easier to use in some op-amp applications.

Comment: I would like to add that if you have a single supply that you need to split into two separate supplies a "virtual ground" ic like the TLE2426 might prove useful.

Comment: So when I'm creating a dual rail power supply with a MAX1044 or 7660, why is there an electrolytic capacitor going from -9V to Ground, instead of from ground to -9V?

Comment: I don't know because I haven't seen the circuit you refer to but I expect there is a good reason. I don't understand why this  is relevant to your original question so maybe consider raising a new question? Also, isn't a cap going from "-9V to Ground" the same as a cap going from "ground to -9V"?